# Python Terminating a process over ssh

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I am trying to terminate a process over ssh.
Now, when terminating the process directly, see commented out line in **init**, the process gets terminated on the remote Host.
Of course, I don't want to immediately terminate, instead terminate all remote processes at the end.

Depending on the option '-t' in subprocess.Popen, different outcomes appear when I try to terminate in the loop at the end of the example:

If '-t' is **not** set, the process is **not** terminated.

If '-t' is set, the process is terminated, but my terminal hides any input and any enter moves the input line around.

Now, why doesn't, without the '-t' option, the process terminate at the loop at the end?

```
serverThreads = []
serverscripts = []
serverscripts.append("script1")
serverscripts.append("script2")

class ServerCaller(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, script):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.script = script
    self.ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", '-t' , username + dataServer, self.script])
    #if I terminate here without '-t' the process on the remote Host is terminated
    #self.term()
def term(self):
    self.ssh.terminate()

for ss in serverscripts:
    serverThreads.append(ServerCaller(ss))

#if I terminate here without '-t' the process on the remote Host is NOT terminated
#if I terminate here with '-t' the process on the remote Host is terminated,
#but my terminal is screwed up
for t in serverThreads:
    t.term()
```

Comment: use fabric or paramiko

Comment: It seems to me this issue is my lack of understanding of python, not that it isn't possible. Terminating a subprocess.Popen is sufficient for me, I just want to understand why the exact same method on the same object doesn't do the same thing.
I have looked into paramiko, but had issues with it, telling me it didn't find my calls executable, but this is another issue

Comment: It's not python, it's ssh.  Writing your own ssh interface is like writing a time interpretation, it will be flakey and someone has already done it better then you can.    I think you have it working and have your answer.  the '-t' forces pseudo-tty, which acts a bit like screen.   I think one can earn a doctorate in tty.

Comment: Well, I am not trying to write my own ssh interface.
Still, I looked further into it and I guess I must switch to paramiko and solve the issue I have there. 

Thank you for your responses

Answer (score 3):

When you use `ssh` to invoke a command on a remote system, and you use `-t` to request a TTY for the remote command, then the remote ssh server will allocate a TTY and launch the remote command with the TTY as its controlling TTY.

When you use `ssh` to invoke a remote command without a TTY, then the remote SSH server will create a set of pipes and launch the remote command with those pipes as the command's standard input, output, and error.

When you terminate your local `ssh` instance, this closes the SSH connection to the server. When this happens, the remote server doesn't explicitly try to kill the remote process that you previously started. The remote server just closes its connection to the remote process--either the TTY or the set of pipes.

If the remote process was started with a TTY (because you specified `-t`), then closing the TTY will cause the remote process to receive a SIGHUP signal. SIGHUP will cause a process to terminate, unless the process specifically arranges to catch or ignore the signal.

If the remote process was started without a TTY, then closing the process's standard input/output/error has no immediate effect. The process won't receive a SIGHUP or other signal. If the process tries to read from standard input, it'll get an end-of-file condition. If it tries to write to stdout/stderr, it'll get a SIGPIPE (which terminates the process by default). If it doesn't access stdin/stdout/stderr, then none of these things will happen and the process could continue running indefinitely.