# JSch ChannelExec OutputStream not showing the program output. However it works with shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell, ssh, jsch

I have a program written in java on my local machine. This program connects to a remote machine using the JSch and shows the output on a `MessageConsole` in the user interface.

I can update the `MessageConsole` in the UI even though my started script doesn't terminate and outputs random numbers. I can read the `OutputStream` and show it on the `MessageConsole`. It works perfectly well.

My problem is the output after starting the C-program. Nothing appears on the `OutputStream`.
The output only appears if the program terminated completely.
all outputs are either done with

```
printf
```

or

```
std::cout
```

If I log into the remote machine manually and start the program by hand, my terminal shows all the outputs instantaneously.

I used the `ChannelExec` to start the program on the remote machine using this:

```
String program = "sudo ./foo/bar.out";
String continousOutput = "sh ~/foo/bar.sh";
//ProcessWorker(String command, SSHSession ssh, GUI gui)
pw = new ProcessWorker(program, ssh, this);
pw.execute();
```

The `ProcessWorker pw` is a `SwingWorker` class to keep the connection open in the background and updating the GUI without locking it up.

This code does all the dirty work. The SSH connection is already established and works.

```
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    try {
        exec = ssh.session.openChannel("exec");
        //command  is the String  program or continousOutput
        ((ChannelExec)exec).setCommand(command);

        exec.setInputStream(null);

        ((ChannelExec)exec).setErrStream(System.err);
        InputStream in = exec.getInputStream();
        exec.connect();

        byte [] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while(true) {
            while(in.available()>0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                String response = new String(tmp, 0, i);
                check(response); //parse response
                System.out.println(response);
                //this.publish(); //desperate try to get something
            }
            if(exec.isClosed()) {
                if(in.available() > 0) continue;
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + exec.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(Exception ee) {}
        }

        exec.disconnect();
    } catch (JSchException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have no more ideas where the problem is. I mean it works perfectly fine with the script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to allocate PTY (pseudo-TTY) for the remote session. That will probably cause the remote process to emit its output as it's running, instead of all at the end:

```
exec.setPty(true);
```

When you run a program through the unix command line, you're communicating with the program through a TTY device. When you launch a program through SSH *without* requesting a PTY (TTY) for the session, you're communicating with the program through a set of pipes, one each for standard input, output, and error.

Unix programs typically buffer their output. The buffering behavior is built into the standard I/O logic used by most C programs (and also used or replicated by perl, python, and so on). When writing to a TTY, the typical behavior is to buffer output data until a full line is written (ie, the program writes a newline character), then the full line is written to the TTY at once. This is what you experience when you run the program interactively.

When writing to a pipe or a file, the default behavior is to buffer until the buffer is filled up. The buffer might be 8 KB in size. This behavior is based on the assumption that the output isn't going to a human and so the program should behave in the most efficient way possible.

Your description sounds like the program is block-buffering its output, and it's not producing enough output to flush the buffer before the program finishes. You want the program to line-buffer its output instead (or unbuffer it completely). There are a few ways to do that:

1. You say the program works correctly when you run it interactively. As I noted, requesting a PTY for the ssh session will probably produce that behavior.
2. You can see if a program like [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) or [`unbuffer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) is available on the system. These can be use to alter the buffering behavior for a process.
3. If you have source code for the program in question, you could add logic to [alter the default buffering behavior](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf), or to [flush the buffer](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) at certain points while the program executes.

Comment: Though using PTY can bring you nasty side effects. If buffering proves to be the culprit, OP should better change the C program not to buffer.

Comment: Thanks for all the given info, this worked pretty good. But it seems like I cannot kill the process using:
    exec.sendSignal("2"); why doesn't it work? Pressing ctrl +c in Terminal does the job normally.

Comment: The remote system is probably running the OpenSSH ssh server. I could be wrong, but [I don't think that server implements sending signals.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581495/13317) Hitting ctrl-C probably kills your local process, causing the remote process to get a SIGHUP when the [TTY closes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47619416/13317)

Comment: Could it be that the running program is executed using sudo and the signal sent isn't? I cannot stop the program using kill pid - but I can stop the program using sudo kill pid. Is there a way to "upgrade" the ChannelExec to su?

Comment: Doesn't matter now. I just made a workaround using "sudo kill $(ps -U root | grep 'a.out' | awk '{print $1}')" in a new channel and like this terminating the first program. Thanks for all your help.